# How to know total number of lines assigned to a mapper

Tags: mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am running a mapreduce job.

I decide number of mappers by setting max_input_split_size field.
Let's say input file is of size 1GB and max_input_split_size = 1mb.
So, each mapper will be assigned some number of lines in the file.

Let's say each mapper got assigned k lines.

Is there a way to find this value k.

Comment: why -1, what is not clear to you in this simple question, please comment.

Comment: each map task returns a value of MAP_INPUT_RECORDS. if each input record corresponds to a new line, there you have it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the value of k i.e, no of lines assigned to a mapper. It will split the file according to the split size and assign the chunk to the mapper.

Comment: my usecase is, to save <key,val> for every 1k calls to map() in a list and process them at once. If i don't know k, i wont be able to do this operation for the last remainder set of keys < 1k.

Comment: I didn't get the usecase. Just a suggestion to use counters in your program if you need to count some values.